# i am trying to add the recyclerview dependency but its not working

Tags: android, xml

i am trying to add recyclerview in android but its not working .the app is running fine but whenever i try to add dependency.

[image]

it generates an error ..would appreciate your answer.

[image]

Installation failed

Comment: try adding the dependancy of appCompact in your gradle

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0' tried but didnt work

Comment: what error did you get when adding the dependancy

Comment: Try uninstalling the previously installed app of your device then build and run again

Comment: when i run the app it says instalation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars

Comment: This happens usually when your device's storage memory is low. Try to free some memory by uninstalling apps.

Comment: i got your point but when i remove the dependency and run the simple hello world  it works

Answer (score 1):

Compile this version. And make sure your Android Studio is up-to-date.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

For the error when installing, try

> Clean Project > Rebuilt Project

Comment: tried but did'nt work ..check the links(images) in my question it may give u the solution

Comment: @Aftabkhan try `minSdkVerison 15`

Comment: There are 3 module in your project. Are you sure run the right one? Which is app module @Aftabkhan

Comment: well i removed the module and open a new project but still stuck am using sdkversion 21

Comment: Did you use updated Android Studio? Use `targetSdkVersion 25`, `compileSdkVersion 25` and `buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"`

Comment: how can i use version 25? i havent updated android studio

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me once i fixed it by disabling instant run in android studio, goto:

```
Android Studio --> File --> Setting --> Build, execution, deploy --> Instant run.
```

and disable instant run.

Comment: did'nt find preferences is it in the project or should i go to the files i.e C:\Project ??

Comment: In android studio go to Files>Settings>Build,exec,deploy>Instantrun and disable it there